# Python subprocess.Popen result stored in a variable

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

I've seen various other posts about this, but unfortunately I still haven't been able to figure this out:

If I do something like this:

```
temp = subprocess.Popen("whoami", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out = temp.communicate()
print(out)
```

then I get something of the form

```
(b'username\n', None)
```

With other attempts (such as adding a .wait()) I've been getting the username on one line, and a 0 as a return code on the next, however only the 0 was being stored in my variable.

Is there an easy way I can format that to store only the username in a variable?  I tried something like out[3:11] but that didn't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way is to use [`subprocess.check_output()`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output):

```
username = subprocess.check_output("whoami").strip()
```

Comment: I'm not a heavy linux user so perhaps I should know this, but what is the 'b' and single quotes surrounding my output from? print(username) results in b'username'

Comment: @Matt: That's unrelated to Linux.  The result is a `bytes` object.  You can turn it into a string by decoding it, e.g. `username.decode("ascii")`.

Answer (score 2):

Adding the [`universal_newlines=True`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments) argument tells `subprocess` calls to return strings. I've been using this instead of explicitly decoding bytestreams.

```
temp = subprocess.Popen("whoami", 
                        shell=True, 
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                        universal_newlines=True)
out = temp.communicate()
print(out)

# prints: ('username\n', None)
```

[Subprocess docs](http://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments):

> If universal_newlines is `True`, the file objects *stdin*, *stdout* and *stderr* will be opened as text streams in *[universal newlines](http://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-universal-newlines)* mode using the encoding returned by `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
username = subprocess.check_output(['whoami']).strip()
```

Or better:

```
username = getpass.getuser()
```

Answer (score 0):

After `communicate`, you can read the return code from `temp.returncode`.

From http://docs.python.org/dev/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.returncode:

> `Popen.returncode`
>   The child return code, set by poll() and wait() (and indirectly by communicate()). A None value indicates that the process hasn’t terminated yet.

If all you care about is that the call succeeds, use `subprocess.check_output`; non-zero return will raise `CalledProcessError`.