# How to catch output of a matlab function from python

Tags: python, matlab, command-line

I'm running the python code below which evaluates mean of an array:

```
def matlab_func1(array):
    p = os.popen('matlab -nodesktop -nosplash  -r "mean('+str(array)+');exit"')
    while 1:
        line = p.readline()
        if not line:
            break
        print line

matlab_func1([1,2,3])
```

From the matlab script below, it can be seen output return to y. I want to catch this output from python.

```
function y = mean(x,dim)
...
...
end
```

The solution must be applicable to the other matlab function. The 'mean' function is just an example.

Comment: Your code isn't formatted properly. You must use four spaces to create a code block, and then another four spaces of indentation for code inside functions and the like.

Comment: Have you considered using e.g. [pymatlab](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pymatlab)?

Comment: @Marcin I installed the pymatlab, however could not find any tutorial to understand how it works. The short script on the pymatlab does not show how to call a specific function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`fprintf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html) to write needed text into `stderr`. Just add an extra argument `2` in the beginning.

```
import subprocess
import os
def matlab_func1(array):
    p = subprocess.Popen(['/home/user/Matlab/bin/matlab', '-nodesktop', '-nosplash', '-r "m = mean(' + str(array) + ');fprintf(2, \'%d\\n\',m);exit" >/dev/null'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    while 1:
        try:
            out, err = p.communicate()
        except ValueError:
            break
        print 'hello' + err

matlab_func1('[1,2,3]')
```

A few things to note:

- Changed the Python command to `subprocess.Popen`, which allows `stderr` piping.
- In Matlab command, use `fprintf` to write wanted info into `stderr`. This can separate code ouput from Matlab's header lines.
- Back into Python, use `Popen.communicate()` to catch `stderr` output.
- The exception `ValueError` handles exit event of Matlab (`p` is closed).

---

EDIT:

## for a function that gives multiple outputs

say a Matlab function is

```
function [y, z] = foo(x)
    y = x+1;
    z = x*20;
end
```

The point is use `fprintf` to throw the output, while doing all other things as you always do normally in Matlab.

### Method 1 - in-line script

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['/home/user/Matlab/bin/matlab', '-nodesktop', '-nosplash', '-r "[y, z] = foo(' + str(array) + ');for ii=1:length(y) fprintf(2, \'%d %d\\n\',y(ii),z(ii)); end; exit" >/dev/null'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

### Method 2 - standalone script

First create a new `caller.m` script

```
[y, z] = foo(x);
for ii=1:length(y)
    fprintf(2, '%d %d\n',y(ii),z(ii));
end
```

Note that `x` is to be assigned when calling from Python; scripts share the same stack. (Remember NOT to `clear` the workspace in the caller script. )

Then, call the script from Python

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['/home/user/Matlab/bin/matlab', '-nodesktop', '-nosplash', '-r "x=' + str(array) + ';caller; exit" >/dev/null'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

### Storing Matlab result in a Python variable

- When passing data through `stdout` / `stderr` pipe:

  Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11248224/3839249) and [`subprocess.check_output()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output).
- When handling serious data like `double` or binary:

  Write the data into an external file with Matlab. Then read this file with Python. A protocol with which both side talk with each other should be defined.

Comment: What if it is a file?

Comment: @yasin.yazici What is "it"?

Comment: What if output of a function is a file?

Comment: The code above raises an error: `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file` I just changed the matlab path

Comment: Do you mean the output data is stored in a file, or the output of your function is a string containing a file path? I can't understand how you make a function output a "file".

Comment: Yes, the old code did. The last edit adds an exception handler that shoud fix this problem.

Comment: Yes, maybe 'file' is misleading. `function[arg1 , arg2] = nameoffunction[arg3,arg4]` assume there is a function like this and I know what the output (arg1,arg2) are. I want to grab these variables(or whatever it is) from workspace.

Comment: I used your last approach : "Write the data into an external file with Matlab. Then read this file with Python"