# Catch Matblab exception from Python

Tags: python, matlab, subprocess, popen

From python script I call a Matlab (v2011B) function using 'subprocess.Popen'. Here is the code from python:

```
command = "matlab -nodisplay -nosplash -r -wait \"MyMatlabFunction(\'%s\',\'%s\'), exit\"" % (var1, var2)
args = shlex.split(command)
process = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, cwd=pathScripts, shell=False)
stdout, stderr= procesoMatlab.communicate()
print stderr
```

On my Matlab function I have a try-catch block like this:

```
try
    do myStuff
catch err
    fprintf(2, getReport(err))
end
```

The point is that when I get an exception on Matlab, the python subprocess module doesn´t receive any value on 'stderr' as it should.

How can I catch the Matlab exception/error in my python script?

Comment: Have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25050771/how-to-catch-output-of-a-matlab-function-from-python

Comment: Yeah Dan, I´read this post, but in my case doesn´t work. Stderr and stdout return always empty. It looks like fprintf doesn´t write on the same pipe of stderr and stdout.
Thanks anyway